# Use find to return only the number

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an external process which essentially needs to call:

```
int myInt = exec('find /v /c "" filepath');
```

It's counting the number of lines in a text file. If there's a better way to get the integer amount that'd also work great.

With find, the full command  returns a fair bit of information other than just the count, for example it returns some dashes for each occurence, the filename, and then :10.

So:

```
---------- filepath :10
```

Is there any way to make find only return the integer part? Or do I need to pipe that output into another process (similar to grep on unix)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using this syntax:

```
type filepath | find /c /v ""
```

Original source [here](http://discussions.virtualdr.com/showthread.php?146504-Is-there-a-DOS-command-to-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file).

```
type filepath
```

returns the lines of the file, while

```
find /c /v ""
```

returns the number of them (apparently the "" search term is a <s>bug</s> feature of find allowing you to count lines).

Comment: I guess you mean `|`, which constitutes a pipe; `||` is a conditional command separator, meaning that the right command is executed only when the left one fails (non-zero return code); `type filepath | find /C /V ""` provides the same result as `find /C /V "" filepath`, but the pipe variant is worse in performance because it has to create additional command prompt instances for both sides of the pipe;

Comment: @aschipfl: You are right about the bad performance, but not in "the same result". If find read its input from Stdin instead of a disk file, it does not display the name of the file (because there is _no file_ in this case).

Answer (score 2):

`find` gives the Output `---------- file.txt :10` when working with files. If it processes STDIN, it gives you only the number:

```
find /v /c "" <file.txt
```

to get this Output into a variable, use this `for` Statement:

```
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^<file.txt') do set myint=%%i
echo %myint%
```

(for use on the commandline, use single `%i` instead of `%%i`)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to pipe the results of `find` into another utility such as [`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)<sup>2<sup>.</sup></sup>

Reason being: The /C option `Displays only the count of lines containing the string.`.

Depending upon the search `filepath` you provide, there could be multiple entries that return.  In order to make sure the results are meaningful, `find` has to provide you with the `filepath` in order to provide you with the appropriate context.

So you would want to issue something<sup>1</sup> like:

```
int myInt = exec('find /v /c "" 'filepath' | findstr /r ': [0-9]*');
```

1 <sub>*Please note: I haven't validated that regex within `findstr` will work.*</sub>
2 <sub>*Apparently `findstr` [returns the entire line as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377867/use-find-to-return-only-the-number#comment54550389_33378071) so you'll need to find a different command.*</sub>

Comment: `findstr` will return the entire line that contains the match, so the output will just be the same... the regex is correct though...

Comment: @aschipfl - Thanks.  I'm going to give up on trying to make it work then.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to replace the `find /v /c "" filepath` portion by the following command line:

```
cmd /V:ON /C "for /F "delims=" %L in ('find /V /C "" "filepath"') do set "LINE=%L" & echo LINE=!LINE:*: =!"
```

Or you create a batch file, say `line_cnt.bat`, with the following similar code, which you call in place of your `find` command line:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
    find /V /C "" "filepath"
') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    echo !LINE:*: =!
)
endlocal
```

In order for this to work, you need either to place it in the proper working directory of your process, to call `line_cnt.bat` using its full path, or to include its containing directory in the search `PATH` of your system.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Windows 7:

`type pretty-print-example.R |\windows\system32\find.exe /i /v /c ""`

output is just the number of lines, 82